# how to limit the korn job to run only from 10 pm to 12 am

Tags: linux, unix

I want to limit the korn job to run between 10 pm to 12 am.Currently it was taking more time to complete than the time frame. Even if its not finished , it as to terminate.

Comment: what you describe is handled by commercial software known as a job-schedulers. `autosys` is one such system. You'll have to find out what is used in you prod. environment, the rules etc, and set up that tool to take care of this OR you can rewrite your script to "poll" to see if there is time to continue. Such arbitrary rules (in my medium experience) often cause more trouble than having a delayed job. Better to focus your energy on getting the system to complete reliably in the time allowed. AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before posting more Qs here.

Comment: We are using autosys here. I don't think autosys can control the shell to limit to run with in specified time frame(10pm to 12 am).

Comment: It wouldn't "control" it, it would kill it if is still running. Find your local `autosys` expert and discuss ;-) . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a cron job, that runs on 12 am. It can look for your job and kill it.
Without a cron job you can do the same with `timeout`.

Another approach is having your script to look at the clock and call some `abort()` function a few seconds before 12 am.
This solution relies on the assumption, that your script is in some long loop, and you can add a function call at a central point (or some central points) where the script will be every few seconds. Using `timeout` seems to be better, but now you can stop your script in a controlled way (and `timeout` is unaware of changes in the clock, the DST or `rdate`).